# How to filter through assertion on deep child div content but yield original element?

Tags: cypress

I have a DOM tree and would like to use `cypress` to do e2e testing.

```
<div class="this-is-an-array">
  <div class="array-item-element">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="array-item-element">
    <div class="very">
      <div class="deep">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="element">
            Expected Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="another">
      <div class="component">
        <div class="dom">
          <div class="tree">
            <button>ButtonToClick</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="array-item-element">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to filter out expected item by asserting on its one child component and click on its another child button through possible code like this:

```
cy.get('.this-is-an-array') // get the root node of array
  .find('.array-item-element') // looping over all items
  .should(($el) => {
    // the very deep child element should contain text of 'Expected Content'
  })
  .get('.another .component .dom .tree button')
  .click()
```

How can I write the `should` clause to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding what you're trying to do, I think what you need is [`cy.within()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Syntax):

```js
cy.get(`.this-is-an-array`)
    .find(`.array-item-element`).then( $elems => {
        $elems.each((idx, elem) => {
            cy.wrap(elem)
                .should(elem => {
                    // assert on child element
                })
                // ensure all subsequent DOM commands are scoped within
                //  the wrapped DOM elem
                .within(() => {
                    cy.get(`.another .component .dom .tree button`)
                        .click();
                });
        });
    });
```